# Ansible play for creating user not setting password

Tags: ansible

Try to set a password randomly and create user with it:

vars:

```
users:
  - username: myuser
    password: "{{ 99999999999999 | random | to_uuid }}"
```

role:

```
- name : Add user accounts
  user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups: sudo,users,admin,adm,ubuntu
    password: '{{ item.password | password_hash("sha512") }}'
  become: true
  with_items: "{{ users }}"

- name: Store users' password in file
  copy:
    content: "{{ item.password }}"
    dest: /home/{{ item.username }}/password.txt
    mode: 0600
    owner: "{{ item.username }}"
  become: true
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

This is provisioned from an OSX ansible workstation, and the instance the user account is provisioned on is an Ubuntu 14.04 instance.

These steps complete without error, and the password.txt is created in the users home folder and populated with a uuid string, which I would expect to be the password. There is also a sha512-like string added to `/etc/shadow` for the relevant user.

`/home/myuser/password.txt`:

```
df81ab5c-c06c-5a2c-b08a-28d52b3a2f6f
```

`/etc/shadow`:

```
myuser:$6$rounds=656000$YKieOBXtL6UKP0lO$5zgyi9D9tmbINkoDVL0EghbCCYInKdyPJ2UFnrDFLAQkB2x7sWBrjKS0uTySvcDGF6jUN1noMvaVD9jp/Dxx71:17193:0:99999:7:::
```

`/var/log/auth.log` after `su myuser` failure:

```
pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname=ubuntu uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=ubuntu rhost=  user=myuser
pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
FAILED su for myuser by ubuntu
- /dev/pts/1 ubuntu:myuser
```

The result however is that the password doesn't work with commands such as `sudo -i` as the user, or `su myuser` from another account.

I've read that OSX vs Linux can result in incompatible keys, but as far as I can tell one of passlib's (which `|password_hash('sha512')` selling points is cross-platform compatibility.

Am I using these tasks/filters correctly or am I missing something?

Comment: There's a question mark in the post, however I don't really understand what the question is.

Comment: Hehe, OK I'll rephrase, though the keywords are `doesn't work` :)

Comment: What OS? What do you mean by "the password doesn't work"? Did you somehow determine what the random value was and tried to login with it? How did you try to login? Is the user created? Does a valid hash show up in /etc/shadow for the new user?

Comment: @GnP good questions, updated

Comment: Thanks! Two more things, can you add the full `/etc/shadow` line for the user and the content for `/var/log/auth.log` when you try to login?

Comment: Everything looks good to me. Ansible and python version? Oh, and the content of `/etc/pam.d/common-password`

Comment: On a second look, neither `shadow(5)` nor `crypt(3)` mention that `rounds` parameter... my `mkpasswd` doesn't add it and neither does my ansible... could you try this hash for that same password: `$6$a1B0cXMrDXuUyF2X$lNOE6BciwSN46NqfVk6GP.Xpu8wSMqrjsJPkUSfbQnPPht/2JcdKwAzNPJF5PdhCQAdGuAm0yxmQyLE9eSFiY0`

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to throw this out there after working on it for 5 years and 9 months. :) I don't know if it had anything to do with the filter, but I have always installed the community.general collection in galaxy and used this filter to generate password, and everything works perfectly.  Again, 5 years after this question was asked.

```
---
  - name: Test
    hosts: localhost
    vars:
      username: "Jimmy"
      password: lookup('community.general.random_string', base64=true)
    tasks:
      - name : Add user accounts
        user:
          name: "{{ username }}"
          password: '{{ password | password_hash("sha512") }}'
        become: true
```